# $n_{th}$ term from the given sum formula of a converging series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

If the sum to $n$ terms is given as $\large{\big(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\big)^2}$   can we find the $n_{th} $ term, ( and thereby the series) , by any  procedure without using prior knowledge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(a_n)$ is a sequence and
$$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$$
then
$$a_n=s_n-s_{n-1}$$

Therefore, just compute the difference between a term and the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

We’re given that

$$\sum_{k=1}^na_k=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2\;,$$

so

$$\begin{align*}a_n&=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)^2-\left(\frac{n(n-1)}2\right)^2\\\\
&=\frac{n^2}4\left((n+1)^2-(n-1)^2\right)\\\\
&=n^3\;.
\end{align*}$$